# PHP.unserialize() дл Javascript - ищу метод

Tags: serialize, node.js, php, javascript, unserialize

В некоторой базе лежат ключи, значения которых являются результатом сериализации переменных PHP, т.е. строчки вида:

```
a:5:{s:2:"id";s:5:"10175";s:12:"character_id";s:2:"16";s:8:"nickname";s:5:"Robot";s:6:"img_id";s:1:"4";s:7:"race_id";s:1:"4"}
```

Эта же база доступна для сервера на node.js, который хочет вытянуть это значение и спарсить его в объект.

Вопрос: какими методами Javascript можно преобразовать сериализованную строку PHP так, чтобы получить на выходе объект?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пакет специальный даже есть для этого, не надо ничего руками писать: [php-unserialize](https://npmjs.org/package/php-unserialize)

Comment: Но если очень хочется, то вот: http://phpjs.org/functions/unserialize/

Comment: отлично! то, что надо, трям!!! :)